# Jquery mouseover event don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write a image share js script. It will add a div wrapper once there is an image in the page. 
For example,

```
<img href="xxx.jpg" />
```

My script will make it to

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img href="xxx.jpg" />
</div>
```

And, there is also a mounseover event in .wrapper class. Everything is going well untill the code structre below. We have a blog site, there is so many div wrapperd the img tag.

```
<div class="a">
    <img href="xxx.jpg" />
</div>
```

while my js script wrapper a "wrapper" class, my mouseover event does not work anymore in these HTML structure. Anyone could tell me what's happened here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post your jquery code .

Comment: hmm..i thought img parameter for this purpose is src..

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the javascript code will help.  From this, my guess is that you aren't binding to `.a` and still bind to `.wrapper`

Answer (score 0):

This might be the case of live event binding and you might need to check jQuery's [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) which, as of 1.7, has been deprecated due to [ON](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - on() does the stuff now that live() used to do

you said - once there is an image, it will wrap - exactly how are you doing this?

The **solution** might be lying there, 
for eg. at the place where you are checking for image and wrapping it, you need to attach mouseover again

```js
//  firstly, why is your image having href=xxx.jpg
//  should be src=xxx.jpg I suppose

$('img[href$="jpg"]').wrap('<div class="wrapper">');

//  Whatever might be your logic above for wrapping
//  you need to again call bind method here OR
//  you need to call one final time at the end of all your code

$('img[href$="jpg"]')
    .parent('.wrapper')
    .bind('mouseover', function() {
        $(this); // $(this) - is your current wrapper div now
        // your code
    });
```

If you don't know when an image comes when you are wrapping it OR it is coming via ajax, then you might need to look at jQuery's [**livequery** plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery)

```
$('div.wrapper').livequery(function() {
    $(this).bind('mouseover', function() {
        // your code
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('img').wrap('<div class="wrapper">');
```

You should wrap it with div and apply `mouseover` on that div instead of the picture.